# Why does field of extended type resolve to null? - Apollo Federation

Tags: apollo-server, typegraphql, apollo-federation

Consider 2 services (A and B). B extends a type that is defined in A, but also adds a new field that's not in A. However, the resolvers in A that return that type don't resolve that field that B introduced (returns `null`). The [Apollo Docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/federation/entities/#extending) mention that B is supposed to resolve the field since B introduced it, but this doesn't seem to be working correctly because the field always resolves to `null`.

I'm using TS, TypeGraphql and have a config similar to the [example docs](https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/tree/master/examples/apollo-federation).

The types look like:

**Service A**

```ts
@Directive(`@key(fields: "_id")`)
@ObjectType()
export class Foo {
  @Field(() => String)
  readonly _id!: ObjectId;

  // this field resolves fine because it was defined in A
  @Field(() => Bar, { nullable: true })
  bar?: Bar;
}
```

**Service B**

```ts
@Directive('@extends')
@Directive(`@key(fields: "_id")`)
@ObjectType()
export class Foo {
  @Field(() => String)
  @Directive('@external')
  readonly _id!: ObjectId;

  // this field resolves to null
  @Field(() => Baz, { nullable: true })
  baz?: Baz;
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what the issue could be / have any solutions in mind?

Comment: You have to add a resolver to B to resolve baz.
Currently you only saying that baz is present in Foo and can be null and it's resolved by service B.
However, the resolver in service B that resolves (```FieldResolver```) baz is missing so it's always *null*.

Comment: An example in my project (which is very similar to the example):
[Product Object](https://github.com/GiovanniZotta/fog_cloud_project/blob/main/graphmarket/services/service-inventories/entities/Product.ts) that has the "new" quantity field. [Product Resolver](https://github.com/GiovanniZotta/fog_cloud_project/blob/main/graphmarket/services/service-inventories/graphql/resolvers/ProductResolver.ts) that resolves the field quantity. Note that the "full" product is resolved in another service.